# Table of categorical variables by a grouping variable in R

Tags: r, frequency

I have a dataset with some categorical variables + a "cluster" variable. For example:

```
time <- c("Morning", "Evening" ,"Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Afternoon")
dollar <- c("1-5", "6-10", "11-15", "1-5", "1-5", "6-10", "6-10")
with_kids <- c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes")
cluster <- c(1,1,2,3,2,2,3)

data <- cbind(time, dollar, with_kids, cluster)
```

How can I create a frequency table of all the categorical variables by "cluster"?

[image: Desired Output -> table on the right (i.e. % within each cluster, for each categorical variable]

Desired output is the table on the right (column % of each categorical variable within each cluster).

I know this code will work for one variable. What is the most efficient way to do it if I have many more categorical variables?

```
table(data$time, data$cluster)
```

Comment: `time$cluster` or `data$cluster`? And it's not `data.frame(time, ...)` instead of `cbind(time, ...)`?

Comment: data$cluster. I made the edit already. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `cbind` Instead use `data.frame` as suggested in the first comment. `cbind` will create a character matrix. Also include your expected output for this example.

Comment: I've included the desired output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of your desired output, but here are two possibilities.

A list of tables:

```
myList <- lapply(dat[head(names(dat), -1)], table, dat$cluster)
myList
$time

            1 2 3
  Afternoon 0 1 1
  Evening   1 1 0
  Morning   1 1 1

$dollar

        1 2 3
  1-5   1 1 1
  11-15 0 1 0
  6-10  1 1 1

$with_kids

      1 2 3
  no  1 1 1
  yes 1 2 1
```

To get a list of proportion tables, you can `lapply` your list of tables using `prop.table` as the function and feed it `margin=2`:

```
lapply(myList, prop.table, margin=2)
$time

                    1         2         3
  Afternoon 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.5000000
  Evening   0.5000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
  Morning   0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000

$dollar

                1         2         3
  1-5   0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000
  11-15 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
  6-10  0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000

$with_kids

              1         2         3
  no  0.5000000 0.3333333 0.5000000
  yes 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.5000000
```

to rbind them together

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dat[head(names(dat), -1)], table, dat$cluster))
          1 2 3
Afternoon 0 1 1
Evening   1 1 0
Morning   1 1 1
1-5       1 1 1
11-15     0 1 0
6-10      1 1 1
no        1 1 1
yes       1 2 1
```

**data**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(time = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Afternoon", 
"Evening", "Morning"), class = "factor"), dollar = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1-5", "11-15", "6-10"), class = "factor"), 
    with_kids = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes"), class = "factor"), cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    3)), .Names = c("time", "dollar", "with_kids", "cluster"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: lmo, one additional question, how can we show the variable names to the left of the variable values? So, I'd like to show "Time" to the left of "Afternoon, Evening and Morning" and "Dollar" to the left of "1-5, 11-15, 6-10", etc. Thanks again!

Comment: This will depend on what you want to do with the output. R does not do this by default and if you want to construct a table for output for a report or paper, you will have to use a package like `xtable` or maybe the `kable` function from `knitr` (I'm not sure if it is that flexible). If you want a table for a report, I'd recommend playing around with `xtable` for a bit and if you can't figure out an adequate structure, asking a new question that links to this one and describes how you want to use the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
time <- c("Morning", "Evening" ,"Morning", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Afternoon")
dollar <- c("1-5", "6-10", "11-15", "1-5", "1-5", "6-10", "6-10")
with_kids <- c("no", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes")
cluster <- c(1,1,2,3,2,2,3)
data <- data.frame(time, dollar, with_kids, cluster)
```

You can use the `dplyr` package and select as many variables as you like

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(interaction(time, cluster, dollar)) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  `interaction(time, cluster, dollar)` count
                                <fctr> <int>
1                        Morning.1.1-5     1
2                      Afternoon.2.1-5     1
3                        Morning.3.1-5     1
4                      Morning.2.11-15     1
5                       Evening.1.6-10     1
6                       Evening.2.6-10     1
7                     Afternoon.3.6-10     1
```